# Buzzing sounds from dimmable floor lamp

Tags: lighting, lamp, ballast

I have a floor lamp which is dimmable and has a box (ballast?) connected and controlling the brightness. It's making a loud buzzing sound when turned on. What can I do to fix it?[image: floor lamp]

Comment: Did it ever work without buzzing? What kind of bulb are you using? If an LED, some dimmers are not designed to work properly with those. If a different bulb doesn't help, try contacting the manufacturer.

Comment: i've de-buzzed a floor-standing torchiere lamp that was using a cheap LED halogen-replacement bulb by adding a 2nd cheap bulb in parallel in reverse polarity. I think some such little bulbs don't have room for a full bridge rectifier, so they only conduct on a positive half-cycle, which annoys the triac's snubber network or doesn't meet it's clamping current.

Answer (score 1):

Has it always buzzed?  First off, make sure you're using the correct bulbs as stated on the sticker that should be somewhere around the sockets. If using acceptable LED bulbs, make sure they are dimmable. Try plugging it into a different outlet; you might be getting some interference from other devices. Last but not least, your dimmer switch it starting to fail.